# Unable to update with "apt-get" getting "429 too many requests" error

Tags: command-line, apt, updates

I am installing update by `sudo apt-get update` but getting the following error:

```
Err:8 https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/any any InRelease
  429  Too Many Requests [IP: 54.215.161.51 443]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/any/dists/any/InRelease  429  Too Many Requests [IP: 54.215.161.51 443]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: You haven't provided your OS/release details, however have you even opened those URLs in a browser? (from a quick scan using a browser it looks to me like your URLs are wrong, typos as with minor changes I could get packages for debian & rhel, but didn't see any Ubuntu packages). What OS/release are you using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: If you visit https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/any in a browser, you'd get `The page you were looking for doesn't exist.` and https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/gpgkey return `Bandwidth or Storage Limit Exceeded` which are to be fixed by the developer/host.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just solved this problem with these steps:

1. Open the terminal.
2. Start your file manager with `sudo`, in my case it's nautilus:

   ```
   sudo nautilus
   ```
3. Navigate to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.
4. Delete the files `packagecloud-shiftky-desktop.list` and `packagecloud-shiftky-desktop.list.save`

Now it will not appear when you run `sudo apt update`.

Answer (score 3):

if you run into the issue use the manual option that is download the release here
https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop/releases. The cause of the error is that the url https://packagecloud.io/shiftkey/desktop/any/dists/any/InRelease has exceeded its allocated monthly bandwidth limit thats why its throwing a 429.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is just a terminal version of the [top answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1274181/1171332):

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/packagecloud-shiftky-desktop.list* $HOME/.local/share/Trash
```